# SharePoint iPad app recommendation?

Tags: recommendations, apple-ios

Does anyone have any experience using an app to access a SharePoint install from an iPad? This isn't for SharePoint development, just for using SharePoint lists without having to fire up my PC.

I'm looking into both **Share Plus Office Mobile Client** and **Filamente SharePoint Client**. Both apps have free versions that I've installed. It seems like there isn't much of a difference between the two other than price. Anyone have any preference or recommendation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My top reasons to pick [SharePlus](http://itunes.apple.com/es/app/shareplus-office-mobile-client/id364895421?mt=8) were:

- Universal Licensing: With one license I can use it on my iPad AND iPhone.
- Background sync
- I felt it more stable

You should by the way, evaluate the [MAC version available at the MAC App Store](http://itunes.apple.com/gb/app/shareplus/id411466135?mt=12).

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about client apps, but I've accessed a SharePoint system from the browser on my iPhone - it worked surprisingly well.

Answer (score 0):

You should try [SharePlus](http://goo.gl/jEYCU). You can try the Lite version for Free. The Pro version has several additional features such as synching whole lists for offline browsing, passcode lock, calendar, blog, and discussion forums specialized views, etc.

It also works for the iPhone (same app, no need to buy it again), and it's available on the mac app store.

Answer (score 0):

PocketPoint is a good option. But it is a paid application and it is available only in iPhone now. But would work in iPad too. :)

PocketPoint support almost all the options that SharePoint provide.

Answer (score 0):

Check out Colligo Briefcase.  I found it much easier to use than any of the above, and the sync concept works great